# How many registrations for Oauth are necessary for multiple mailboxes and multiple servers?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, office365, phpmailer, imap

I've read the last days multiple documentations and tutorials, but didn't find the answer for my question, although it is in my opinion an obviously elementary question.

We use two servers and three Office365 email addresses (`report@<companyname>.de`, `service@<companyname>.de` & `support@<companyname>.de`). Both servers use a PhpMailer to send emails from theses email addresses via SMTP. One server additionally fetches the emails from these three addresses via IMAP in the same intra net php program, where the PhphMailer is located.

Because Basic Auth is deprecated, i have to switch to Oauth (for Microsoft Oauth 2.0). Therefor i need to know, how many registrations are necessary for my usecase.

I think at least two - one for each server. But is one (for each server) for all our `@<companyname>.de` email adresses enough?

Comment: By server you mean PHP server? No you wouldn't need to register each one separately (unless you really want to), they could use the same app registration in your O365 tenant if you want - they can connect using the same client credentials. You're registering an application as the client, not a physical server. If all the email addresses you're trying to interact with are in the same O365 tenant you should only need 1 app registration, the app just needs the appropriate permissions in the Graph API.

Comment: That said, it's quite likely that your O365 account will only allow you to send from the email address that is also the username associated with the token, so you may need to set up different credentials for each one, depending on how your account is configured.

Comment: Tanks for the fast answer. One server has the intra net php app with PhpMailer included and the other server has only a "naked" PhpMailer. The second server is a xampp server. Aren't they both php servers because Php is installed?

Comment: @Synchro not if you use an app registration and grant it general permissions to read/write to mailboxes

Comment: @biberman well if they're running PHP code then yes. Although in this context, they're _clients_ of the Office365 because they're making requests to O365 to send/receive data. Whether they're servers for other purposes doesn't really matter (I was just echoing your terminology in my comment) - as I said, the physical computers involved are largely irrelevant to what you need to do here. You can have many different programs all using the same O365 app registration credentials if you want to. There are good and bad points to doing that, you just have to decide how to organise it yourself.

Comment: If you convert your comments to an answer, i will accept it...

Comment: @Synchro How would i set up different credentials for each email address? Do i need to register the app for each address -> multiple app registration in AAD? Or does each email address need an own tenant where the app must be registered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't need to register each one separately (unless you really want to), they could use the same app registration in your O365 tenant if you want - they can connect using the same client credentials. You're registering an application as the client, not a physical server. You can have many different programs all using the same O365 app registration credentials if you want to. There are good and bad points to doing that, you just have to decide how to organise it yourself.

If all the email addresses you're trying to interact with are in the same O365 tenant you should only need 1 app registration, the app just needs the appropriate permissions in the Graph API.

Comment: Because i fail to set the appropriate permissions, i created a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73879796/how-to-configure-an-app-in-azure-portal-for-multiple-email-addresses-that-are-i). Could you have a look?